# array_udiff returning a difference when one doesn't exist

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have the following 2 arrays:

```
$combos = array (
  0 =>
  array (
    1064 => '3438',
    1065 => '3440',
  ),
  1 =>
  array (
    1064 => '3439',
    1065 => '3440',
  ),
  2 =>
  array (
    1064 => '3438',
    1065 => '3441',
  ),
  3 =>
  array (
    1064 => '3439',
    1065 => '3441',
  ),
);

$productCombos = array (
  0 =>
  array (
    1065 => '3440',
    1064 => '3438',
  ),
  1 =>
  array (
    1065 => '3441',
    1064 => '3438',
  ),
  2 =>
  array (
    1065 => '3440',
    1064 => '3439',
  ),
  3 =>
  array (
    1065 => '3441',
    1064 => '3439',
  ),
);
```

I then use `array_udiff` to see if `$combos` and `$productCombos` contain all the same arrays:

```
$diff = array_udiff($combos, $productCombos, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a < $b)  return -1;
    else if ($a > $b) return 1;
    else return 0;
});
```

This returns:

```
array (
  2 =>
  array (
    1064 => '3438',
    1065 => '3441',
  )
```

But I don't understand why, since this array is contained in both variables. In other words:

```
$combos = array (
    2 =>
        array (
            1064 => '3438',
            1065 => '3441',
        )
    );

$productCombos = array(
    1 =>
        array (
            1065 => '3441',
            1064 => '3438',
        )
    );

$combos[2] == $productCombos[1] // true
```

So why would `array_udiff` be returning this as a difference?

Comment: The values are in a different order; that's a difference

Comment: Yes, but they are still 'equivalent' arrays. Same key/values. `==` doesn't care about order. I think my problem might be that the diff never returns `-1` or `1` because comparing arrays with `<` or `>` seems to always return `false`.

Comment: Correct. `array_udiff()` requires you to create a proper ordering of elements. `array1 < array2` converts both arguments to `Strings` before handling the comparison and this results in comparing `Array` with `Array` each time.

Comment: equivalent !== same

Comment: You can use [sort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) first then compare your array after that

Comment: @AmrAly thanks that's what I needed.